# Vlc Notification Bubble delay - Libnotify Problem

Tags: 12.04, vlc, libnotify

I have a problem with VLC on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.I have activated libnotify on `VLC Preferences` but I noticed that the notification bubble delays when I change a few songs continuously.For a example lets assume that my playlist is sorted with letters of the English alphabet from letter A to F.If I want for example to listen to the song with the letter D I have to press the `Next` button for 3 times.When I do that VLC will start playing the song with the letter D,but the notification bubble on the top left is still in the song with the letter A and gradually will change from one song to another and eventually will reach the song with the letter D which is the current one.So how can I make the notification bubble to follow my changes ?

Comment: It is not possible, notify-send queues up messages, the default timeout for that is 5 sec, and it cannot be changed. see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508

Comment: yes,but I have asked also in the videolan forums and a member responded me that his notification bubble works perfectly with vlc.So I guess from what you told me and what the videolan forum member told me that this is not something like a predefined/non changeable setting.